# Lavarel don't accept Js Date format from Vue with axios, catch an 500 Internal Error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, client-side

I have an Vue component, passing dates with axios requests.

I have an input where i introduce the date, for ex. ("2021-03-06"), it's working, but if i use an datePicker it's doesn't.

```
public function store()
    {

        $attributes = request();

        Task::create([
            'name' => $attributes['name'],
            'client_id' => $attributes['client_id'],
            'task_date' => $attributes['task_date'],
            'state' => 1,
            'type' => $attributes['type'],
            'details' => $attributes['details'],
            'invoiced_date' => $attributes['invoiced_date'],
            'programing_worked_minutes' => $attributes['programing_worked_minutes'],
            'support_worked_minutes' => $attributes['support_worked_minutes'],
            'closed_date' => null,
        ]);
        return 1;
    }
```

```
        <datepicker
                    v-model="task.task_date"
                    :lower-limit="new Date()"
                    placeholder="click here to choose a date"
                    id="task_date"
                    name="task.task_date"
                    class="block rounded p-0 shadow-inner  border-gray-300 w-1/2"
                    required
                />
```

```
export default {
    name: "addTask",
    components: {
        Datepicker
    },
    data() {
        return {
            task: {
                name: null,
                client_id: null,
                task_date: null,
                type: null,
                details: null,
                invoiced_date: null,
                programing_worked_minutes: null,
                support_worked_minutes: null,
            },

            message: "",
            visual_spinner: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendData() {
            this.message = '';
            this.visual_spinner = true;
            axios.post('/create-task', {
                name: this.task.name,
                client_id: this.task.client_id,
                task_date: this.task.task_date,
                type: this.task.type,
                details: this.task.details,
                invoiced_date: this.task.invoiced_date,
                programing_worked_minutes: this.task.programing_worked_minutes,
                support_worked_minutes: this.task.support_worked_minutes,

            })
                .then((response) => {
                    this.onSuccess();
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);

                });
        },
```

So, the request it working well, the problem is with the format Date ,
if is **2021-03-01** its working but if it's
**Sat Mar 13 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)** not working

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is with the date format, you could format it into the expected format **before** submitting it to the database.

Once the JavaScript date format `Sat Mar 13 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)` has been received by Laravel, you could format it using [Carbon PHP library](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) which already comes with the framework. i.e:

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;


$javaScriptDateFormat = "Sat Mar 13 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)";
$date = explode("(", $javaScriptDateFormat, 2)[0];
$formattedDate = Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d');
print_r($formattedDate); // "2021-03-13"
```

## ADDENDUM

<s>Another alternative is that you could use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to format the 'date string' got from `datePicker` `Sat Mar 13 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)` into the expected format **before** sending it to the server. i.e:</s>

```js
import moment from "moment";

const date = new Date("Sat Mar 13 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)");
console.log(moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));  // 2021-03-13
```

Since [Moment.js has been discontinued](https://github.com/moment/moment#project-status), as suggested by @AnuratChapanond, use [Day.js](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) instead as an alternative.

```js
import dayjs from "dayjs";

const date = new Date("Sat Mar 13 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)");
console.log(dayjs(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));  // 2021-03-13
```

Comment: moment.js is discontinued, use day.js instead

Comment: @AnuratChapanond, I've updated the answer. Thank you for your response. I was unaware of that since I mostly work with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Sun Mar 07 2021 00:17:59 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time) vs 2021-03-07 is not the same.
500 internal error means something happens on server side.
I guess, the problem is coming from your Laravel Database Schema
as example:  `$table->dateTime('task_date');` replace with `$table->string('task_date');`
Then migrate.

Comment: I personally think it's bad advice to keep a `date` as a `VARCHAR(...)` data type. Considering that he is mostly interested in the date, `$table->date('task_date');` [date()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-date) would sound optimal. Nonetheless, I think this is **not** OP's current problem.

Comment: in db is ```date``` not ```VARCHAR```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used

```
formatDate(date) {
            var d = new Date(date),
                month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                day = '' + d.getDate(),
                year = d.getFullYear();

            if (month.length < 2)
                month = '0' + month;
            if (day.length < 2)
                day = '0' + day;

            return [year, month, day].join('-');
        }
```

to convert
`Sat Mar 13 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`
into `2021-03-13`